# Installing RcppOctave package in R

Tags: r, package, installation, octave

I'm trying to install RcppOctave package in R on Windows, which is supposed to connect R with Octave. Installation seems to be going fine until Octave starts to work inside R. I suspect the following part is the reason

```
warning: unable to find mkoctfile in expected location: 'C:\Octave\Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2\bin\mkoctfile-3.6.4'
warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status
```

The whole process then ends with an error and doesn't install the package. Could this be the reason for the error, or should I look somewhere else? I have installed Visual Studio 2010, which is supposed to compile oct files. mkoctfile is at that location.

Comment: Visual Studio has nothing to with this.  _All_ R extensions use gcc via MinGW.

Comment: It seems the problem of your Octave installation.  Perhaps some files or libraries are missing.  I am on different OS, but got the same error, which has been resolved after installing libraries suggested by the error message.  What did your error message say?

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel This means that it shouldn't be a problem if I have the correct version of Rtools installed?

Comment: You should add if the mkoctfile can be found at the above location from the message or not. If not you have to adjust the path.

Comment: @Kota Mori I'm not good at reading this, but it seems the error is in these lines: ` # Copying Octave modules to directory 'C:/Users/Gregor/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RcppOctave/modules/i386'
cp: cannot stat '*.oct ` : No such file or directory
make: *** [OctaveModule] Error 1'. Can you tell me, which libraries were needed in your case?

Comment: It works fine on linux.  This can be an issue of Windows compatibility.  The author of the package may still be investigating.    https://github.com/renozao/RcppOctave/issues/11

Comment: @Kota Mori This specific problem seems to be with Octave 4.0.0. I have 3.6.4., which is recommended by the package. The log outputs also differ a lot. Can I somehow check if I'm missing any libraries?

Comment: When I did `install.packages("RcppOctave")`, I got an error message suggesting a set of required libraries.  By library I mean external software, not an R package.  In my case, octarve-dev was missing (I am on Ubuntu linux).  Your system may require something different.  Perhaps you should contact the author of the package how you can install the package on Windows system.

Comment: Could it be that the gcc compiler is somehow broken? In the readme of the package it says to download Windows native gcc 4.9.2 toolchain, which I did and extracted to c:/Rtools/mingw64. Maybe something went wrong here?